# Не стартует weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic

Выдает такую ошибку
    .

```
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
.
CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\ORACLE~1\jdk\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b3\lib\ant-contrib.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\modules\features\oracle.wls.common.nodemanager_2.0.0.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\com.oracle.cie.config-wls-online_8.1.0.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derbynet.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\common\derby\lib\derby.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\xqrl.jar
.
PATH=;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\native\win\32;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\org.apache.ant_1.9.2\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\ORACLE~1\jdk\jre\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\ORACLE~1\jdk\bin;C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\Intel\SHARED~2\cpp\Bin\Intel64;C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\Intel\SHARED~1\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\Intel\SHARED~1\redist\ia32\compiler;C:\PROGRA~2\Caminova\DOCUME~1\;C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\WINDOW~1;C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\WINDOW~1;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WINDOW~1\v1.0\;C:\PROGRA~2\WIC4A1~1\Shared;C:\PROGRA~2\ATITEC~1\ATI.ACE\CORE-S~1;C:\PROGRA~1\Broadcom\BROADC~1.11\Driver;C:\PROGRA~1\WIDCOMM\BLUETO~1\;C:\PROGRA~1\WIDCOMM\BLUETO~1\syswow64;C:\PROGRA~1\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http:\\hostname:port\console        *
***************************************************
starting weblogic with Java version:
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\ORACLE~1\jdk\bin\java -server -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8453,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE  -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.policy  -Xverify:none -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\ORACLE~1\jdk\jre\lib\endorsed;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\endorsed  -ea -da:com.bea... -da:javelin... -da:weblogic... -ea:com.bea.wli... -ea:com.bea.broker... -ea:com.bea.sbconsole... -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server      weblogic.Server
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453
<17.07.2014 20:18:42 GST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling the CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true.> 
<17.07.2014 20:18:44 GST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG128 to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true.> 
<17.07.2014 20:18:50 GST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM Version 24.51-b03 from Oracle Corporation.> 
<17.07.2014 20:18:53 GST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 12.1.3.0.0  Wed May 21 18:53:34 PDT 2014 1604337 > 
<17.07.2014 20:19:02 GST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.> 
<17.07.2014 20:19:02 GST> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool.> 
<17.07.2014 20:19:02 GST> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002942> <CMM memory level becomes 0. Setting standby thread pool size to 256.> 
<17.07.2014 20:19:07 GST> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.> 
<17.07.2014 20:19:21 GST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090082> <Security initializing using security realm myrealm.> 
<17.07.2014 20:19:21 GST> <Critical> <Security> <BEA-090402> <Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid. The user name or password or both from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.> 
<17.07.2014 20:19:21 GST> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: A MultiException has 8 exceptions.  They are:
1. weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid. The user name or password or both from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.security.SecurityService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService
5. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime.internal.RuntimeServerService errors were found
6. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime.internal.RuntimeServerService
7. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.cacheprovider.CacheProviderServerService errors were found
8. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.cacheprovider.CacheProviderServerService

A MultiException has 8 exceptions.  They are:
1. weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid. The user name or password or both from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.security.SecurityService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService
5. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime.internal.RuntimeServerService errors were found
6. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime.internal.RuntimeServerService
7. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.cacheprovider.CacheProviderServerService errors were found
8. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.cacheprovider.CacheProviderServerService

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:88)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:269)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid. The user name or password or both from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted.
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1017)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.postInitialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1131)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.postInitialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:943)
    at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:159)
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:78)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090304]Authentication Failed: User weblogic javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090302]Authentication Failed: User weblogic denied
    at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.login(LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:267)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper$1.run(LoginModuleWrapper.java:110)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper.login(LoginModuleWrapper.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<17.07.2014 20:19:24 GST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED.> 
<17.07.2014 20:19:24 GST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down.> 
<17.07.2014 20:19:24 GST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN.> 
Stopping Derby server...
Derby server stopped.
```

Comment: @ttt, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Молодой человек, Weblogic это не игрушка, бросьте его и займитесь Tomcat'ом - вы даже логи не умеет прочитать (а там кстати примерно то же самое и написано)

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема в файле boot.properties, вы видимо при первом запуске начали вписывать пароль, а он в cmd не отображается, испугались и ввели "белеперду" и прописали неправильный пароль.

Найдите его в папке middleware и откройте блокнотом. Исправьте файл и заново запустите Oracle.